# Plot model in log-log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following R code to fit a linear model on some data:

```
benchmark <- read.csv("data.csv")
model <- lm(formula = y ~ x, data = benchmark)
summary(model)
ggplot(benchmark, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ x)
```

The result is:

[image]

It looks weird to me because the axis are powers of two, so most data points are concentrated at the left.
My guess is that it will be better to use a log-log scale, but i don't know how to do it properly. For example, using

```
scale_x_log10() +
scale_y_log10()
```

i get now

[image]

which i think is wrong.

EDIT: share the data

```
1,          3.50225e-07
2,          4.75979e-07
4,          2.65479e-07
8,          3.55327e-07
16,         2.98107e-07
32,         3.11732e-07
64,         2.40219e-07
128,        2.78199e-07
256,        3.27337e-07
512,        2.79105e-07
1024,       7.27129e-07
2048,       4.59182e-07
4096,       7.8944e-07
8192,       1.1326e-06
16384,      2.11749e-06
32768,      3.53295e-06
65536,      4.822e-06
131072,     7.3658e-06
262144,     1.2835e-05
524288,     2.34737e-05
1048576,    4.86131e-05
2097152,    9.87735e-05
4194304,    0.000215783
8388608,    0.000510538
16777216,   0.00108616
33554432,   0.00226483
67108864,   0.00480124
134217728,  0.00982463
268435456,  0.0198695
536870912,  0.0402285
1073741824, 0.0818823
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(benchmark)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(benchmark, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks but i tried that combination, the result is the same thing you see in my last screenshot.

Comment: OK, the axis do not show powers of two. If you  transform any of them or both you will break the straight line.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Ok, i added the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for the following.
`glm` code borrowed from a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264521/plot-model-in-log-log-scale/73265655#comment129390049_73264590).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(benchmark, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'glm', formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, 
              method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = 'log'))) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log2',
                     breaks = trans_breaks("log2", function(x) 2^x),
                     labels = trans_format("log2", math_format(2^.x)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Data

```r
x<-'1,          3.50225e-07
2,          4.75979e-07
4,          2.65479e-07
8,          3.55327e-07
16,         2.98107e-07
32,         3.11732e-07
64,         2.40219e-07
128,        2.78199e-07
256,        3.27337e-07
512,        2.79105e-07
1024,       7.27129e-07
2048,       4.59182e-07
4096,       7.8944e-07
8192,       1.1326e-06
16384,      2.11749e-06
32768,      3.53295e-06
65536,      4.822e-06
131072,     7.3658e-06
262144,     1.2835e-05
524288,     2.34737e-05
1048576,    4.86131e-05
2097152,    9.87735e-05
4194304,    0.000215783
8388608,    0.000510538
16777216,   0.00108616
33554432,   0.00226483
67108864,   0.00480124
134217728,  0.00982463
268435456,  0.0198695
536870912,  0.0402285
1073741824, 0.0818823
'
benchmark <- read.csv(textConnection(x))
names(benchmark) <- c("x", "y")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I'm not familiar with glm, i barely know lm (and model fitting in general). I like how this plot looks. However, what i don't understand is why this is so different to use something like `scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log2')`. The result with glm still look like a perfect fit, while the other not. I initially thought that what i got in my second screenshot was wrong somehow, just because it looks so off compared to the original plot.

Comment: @fulem The x values are in a geometric progression of ratio 2, when plotted with `trans = "log2"` the scale becomes linear. I have formatted the x axis labels to make this graphically obvious.